# pcapy.PcapError: eth1: You don't have permission to capture on that device

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I am trying to run  pcapy_sniffer.py  but i get this

pcapy.PcapError: eth1: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on linux or OS X try running as root or with `sudo`, otherwise if you're on windows try running as administrator.

Comment: @user6269492 Could you please accept my answer if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is possible run into a docker container as not root user?

Comment: @EnriqueAlcocer I mean docker allows you to run non-root containers, but those non-root containers cannot privilege escalate or that would be considered a security flaw. Those containers only have the permissions of the user who created them. Specifically containers are allowed access to certain devices, and those devices the container can access are limited to the access the user running the container has. So no, running in a non-root container won't work even for just capturing network traffic in the container.

Comment: @EnriqueAlcocer The answer to that is a bit too complicated for an SO comment, but docker containers don't have their own `/dev` filesystem, and just pass through access from the host to those devices. Beyond there are also "capabilities", which can give certain subsets of permissions to a process, and containers can often be given capabilities for the processes that they run. These capabilities still need to be given by a user who has the privilege to assign capabilities (usually root). https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html